# CSS optimization for 4:3 screens

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with optimization in **CSS**.

In my website i have **video background** and on 16:9 screen it works perfect, but on 4:3 screen there's gray margins on the top and the bottom.

Is there any way in CSS (using media query or something) to set image or color background ?

So i know how media query works, but i need code so i don't need to use px, but screen ratio ?

```
    #Homepage{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    z-index:2;
    background-position:center;}

    video.bgvid { 
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height:100vh;
    border:1px solid red;
    z-index: -100;
    background: url("../img/bg3.jpg") no-repeat;}
video{width:100%;}

.overlay{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);}
```

Comment: May be you are looking for something like @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 4/3) { ... }

Comment: where's your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this helps me `@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 4/3) { ... }`